# How can I add spacing to my answer here?

Tags: support, markdown

I posted an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424067/mathbba2-backslash-0-0-not-affine-variety/424091#424091) to a question and point number 2 of my answer seems too long. I would like to break it into separate paragraphs. However everytime I try to do  this it breaks the numbering environment. Also I can't go `\vspace{5mm}`, `\medskip` or do `//`  like in the normal `\begin{enumerate}` environment to add spacing. What can I do here? Can someone help me add spacing please?

Comment: Related question: [Numbers after paragraph breaks turn into 1's](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/numbers-after-paragraph-breaks-turn-into-1s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mimic the indentation by just adding a space in front of the new paragraph, like so:

1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent at sem interdum sem aliquet porttitor. Ut eleifend ligula at tristique fermentum. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur lacinia ligula sed sem pulvinar ultrices. Phasellus id bibendum mi. Nulla sodales quam a turpis luctus fermentum.

   Donec id turpis sagittis, fermentum quam in, posuere neque. Suspendisse sollicitudin lorem rhoncus, blandit risus a, pellentesque dui. Nam at lorem mattis urna fermentum mattis. Praesent lobortis, lacus a ultricies lobortis, ipsum orci tincidunt dolor, non tincidunt urna magna vel dolor. Maecenas ac luctus velit, quis aliquet est.
2. Quisque tristique nulla accumsan nunc vulputate lobortis. Phasellus tempor bibendum eros nec venenatis. Sed tempor dictum velit id pretium. Praesent sit amet libero ipsum.

Comment: Thanks Antonio!

Comment: I appreciate the opportunity to learn this myself, too :)